# Using CCBReader to load a scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a `CCScrollView` that is opened up when the user clicks a button. I also want to "re-initialize" the class that handles the UI elements of this `CCScrollView`. I am doing this by calling `[CCBReader load:@"Shop"];` `Shop` being the custom class of this `CCScrollView`. `Shop` sets all the labels and buttons of the `CCScrollView`.

Opening the `CCScrollView` (located in `MainScene`):

```
-(void)openShop
{
        [CCBReader loadAsScene:@"Shop"];
        CCScrollView *scroll = [[CCScrollView alloc]initWithContentNode:shopNode];
        [shopNode setContentSizeInPoints:(CGSizeMake(320, 1000))];
        [scrollContainer addChild:scroll z:0 name:@"scrollName"];
        [scroll setContentSizeInPoints:(CGSizeMake(320.0, 370.0))];
        [scroll setHorizontalScrollEnabled:NO];
        [scroll setPosition:(CGPointMake(0, 70))];
}
```

The init method of `Shop`:

```
-(id)init
{
    if ([super init]) {
        if (i == 0) {
            cell1.string = @"hello";
            i++;
        } else {
            cell1.string = @"ffff";
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

So what I trying to make happen is, when I first run the program and all the classes are initialized, the string of `cell1` is "hello", and it adds 1 to i. Then, when I open the `CCScrollView`, `Shop` should be initialized again and since i is 1, the string of `cell` should change to "ffff". The problem is that it isn't changing the string of `cell1.` I can put in an `NSLog` that displays random text and that will work perfectly fine, but `cell1`'s string will not change. Why is this?

Comment: init will only ever be executed once, when the object of class Shop is created.

Comment: I placed an NSLog into `init` and it outputs every time I open the scroll view

Comment: That's because every time you open the scroll view a new Shop instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you open the scroll view a new Shop instance is created. The previous instance that has the value of 'i' set to 1 is deallocated by this time, so every time you start over with i being 0.

The quick fix would be to make i a static variable outside the @interface. I strongly suggest renaming it though.

```
static int index = 0;

-(id)init
{
    if ([super init]) {
        if (index == 0) {
            cell1.string = @"hello";
            index++;
        } else {
            cell1.string = @"ffff";
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

The better way would be to store the index value outside of shop and pass it to the shop instance when you create it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, tried this but I am getting the same result, as in the cell1 doesn't display the updated text. What would be the correct way to store index and pass it to shop? The only way to pass data that I am familiar with is using view controllers